# Wordpress & Genesis Framework linking

Tags: php, wordpress, genesis

I created a Page in wordpress called add-a-contact.  Contains name, email, and phone number.

I created a custom php page called  contact-insert.php   which will accept the form fields and insert into a database.

How do I link the Page add-a-contact so when the submit button is clicked it posts to contact-insert.php

I was asked to take over from a previous developer and haven't figured out how Genesis and Word Press are linked together.   I was told I can't put the source in functions.php.

Was wondering if anyone could shed some light on this?

Jim

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly. You want to have your add-a-contact WordPress Page, have its own php code applied, in WordPress we call it custom page template.

You said, you created a page called  contact-insert.php. I would suggest to turn it into a simple page template in your Genesis child theme.

For sample code of how a custom page template looks like in genesis child theme, have a look in this tutorial http://www.wpmayor.com/creating-custom-template-in-genesis-framework/

To create custom template in Genesis you only need few things to do it right.

1. Put all your code in a function, and then hook that function to some hook, in our case, I suggest do it to genesis_loop
2. May remove the default loop from that page
3. Last line of the php file should have **genesis();** so it inherit everything from Genesis to become part of Genesis theme.

e.g.

```
remove_action( 'genesis_loop', 'genesis_do_loop' );
add_action( 'genesis_loop', 'child_do_custom_loop' );

function child_do_custom_loop() {
   //your custom php code here
}
```

Then apply this template your add-a-contact page from custom page template setting https://en.support.wordpress.com/pages/page-attributes/#template

Answer (score 0):

While I would definitely recommend Mohsin's approach, a simpler answer would be to have your contact form's action attribute point to the URL of your custom .php page, so that on submission, custom page can read values from the `$_POST` superglobal (or via `filter_input()` if you're feeling fancy).